# Convert string in Image and blit in Pyglet

Tags: image, python-3.x, png, pyglet

I want to convert a string that contains the data of an PNG image in image again and blit in Pyglet. But I didn't. Show this error:

Error:

```
  File "a14.py", line 52, in __init__
      self.sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img, 0, 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pyglet-1.2.4-py3.4.egg/pyglet/sprite.py", line 234, in __init__
      AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'get_texture'
```

Code: -----------------------------------------------------------------

imageData:

```
8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a 0000 000d 4948 4452
0000 0010 0000 001c 0806 0000 0068 313f
1a00 0000 0473 4249 5408 0808 087c 0864
8800 0002 0249 4441 5438 8d95 552d 8cdb
3018 7dad 0a02 47a6 2bec 58d8 32b4 c2b0
8d4c 0a8c 74c4 5649 d819 e6c0 a181 05e6
5848 1593 d319 562a c958 60c7 3c66 5898
69a4 d0ac 0349 9c38 3fd5 ee49 561c e77b
ef7b 9fe3 2f59 ecf3 fc8a 191c 291d ad7d
cb73 eb7e 758b 287c 562f 6400 a27a 1a52
6a89 8c04 8e94 1a62 515d e0c6 0a1b 6c81
2241 e145 a364 8b7e 092d b9a8 2e00 8040
f1b9 eab0 6f5c 2ca7 c881 e237 c900 b06b
ca5c b664 e212 437e 0b96 730f 348b a0b5
ae47 6f3e 2c61 0500 8245 0009 e178 be21
b770 1c07 5a96 f555 6b43 340e ee7f ff42
5a1d c616 4838 e9ec fed3 07fc fdf9 3851
0217 5dd6 34ab 27ea 54bb e102 5a96 803a
8d04 572f 1f3f 83f5 ea76 d2ac 0e06 e078
3e92 700d b60e ac04 169a 7370 0570 d52c
32a3 5dbb 35f6 797e 5d36 22b6 7500 5a96
c6c9 4c62 0083 93b8 a3b4 b33c 83b4 3ae0
fd97 1fdd 1e0c 558f 94a2 70eb f7cd 9b43
b50d d726 a64f 1e09 f41b 292c 5310 9740
7905 183f 770e c8c6 12b1 7a81 b8c4 3c10
3e1b 9101 80f1 f3cc 3968 d076 e2ff c208
482f 3135 b722 aefc 8a94 6c2c c2b0 046b
0fa4 9780 cbd8 7426 571c 5040 8a4e 84f1
335e 5e5f a705 36c1 3b48 d422 2d3c 7542
db83 a590 c8b6 299e 1eee a605 5a91 4b90
c10f bd9b b5b7 307b f0f4 7087 f3a1 dbc0
5248 33e7 6189 5248 9c0f 172b fba4 833e
fa22 7358 0cff 0bdf 9fff cc06 0fb3 4f3a
88dc 7414 148b 0a49 b8c6 8e56 e32f d254
f010 5a31 c4a2 8256 cc7c 8d67 1d4c 89c4
a276 e54c b8fb 0775 650d 8c04 f5e9 f200
0000 0049 454e 44ae 4260 82
```

---

the code that I tried:

```
import pyglet
import binascii

class Window(pyglet.window.Window):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        imgData = #ABOVE /\, IN MY CODE IMAGEDATA IS HERE

        img = "".join(imgData.split())

        img = binascii.unhexlify(img)

        self.sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img, 0, 0)

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.sprite.draw()

def main():
    window = Window(width=640, height=480, caption='Pyglet')
    pyglet.app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

There is a way to do it, if yes, how? Can someone help me?

Comment: PNG image is a specialized file format (like JPG, GIF, BMP) with compressed data. `Sprite` expects `class` with image data (without compression), not `bytes array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sprite` expects `image` object not `bytes array`. You can use `io.BytesIO` to use bytes as file object and then load it using `image.load()`.

Full working example

```
import pyglet
import binascii
import io

imgData = '''8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a 0000 000d 4948 4452
0000 0010 0000 001c 0806 0000 0068 313f
1a00 0000 0473 4249 5408 0808 087c 0864
8800 0002 0249 4441 5438 8d95 552d 8cdb
3018 7dad 0a02 47a6 2bec 58d8 32b4 c2b0
8d4c 0a8c 74c4 5649 d819 e6c0 a181 05e6
5848 1593 d319 562a c958 60c7 3c66 5898
69a4 d0ac 0349 9c38 3fd5 ee49 561c e77b
ef7b 9fe3 2f59 ecf3 fc8a 191c 291d ad7d
cb73 eb7e 758b 287c 562f 6400 a27a 1a52
6a89 8c04 8e94 1a62 515d e0c6 0a1b 6c81
2241 e145 a364 8b7e 092d b9a8 2e00 8040
f1b9 eab0 6f5c 2ca7 c881 e237 c900 b06b
ca5c b664 e212 437e 0b96 730f 348b a0b5
ae47 6f3e 2c61 0500 8245 0009 e178 be21
b770 1c07 5a96 f555 6b43 340e ee7f ff42
5a1d c616 4838 e9ec fed3 07fc fdf9 3851
0217 5dd6 34ab 27ea 54bb e102 5a96 803a
8d04 572f 1f3f 83f5 ea76 d2ac 0e06 e078
3e92 700d b60e ac04 169a 7370 0570 d52c
32a3 5dbb 35f6 797e 5d36 22b6 7500 5a96
c6c9 4c62 0083 93b8 a3b4 b33c 83b4 3ae0
fd97 1fdd 1e0c 558f 94a2 70eb f7cd 9b43
b50d d726 a64f 1e09 f41b 292c 5310 9740
7905 183f 770e c8c6 12b1 7a81 b8c4 3c10
3e1b 9101 80f1 f3cc 3968 d076 e2ff c208
482f 3135 b722 aefc 8a94 6c2c c2b0 046b
0fa4 9780 cbd8 7426 571c 5040 8a4e 84f1
335e 5e5f a705 36c1 3b48 d422 2d3c 7542
db83 a590 c8b6 299e 1eee a605 5a91 4b90
c10f bd9b b5b7 307b f0f4 7087 f3a1 dbc0
5248 33e7 6189 5248 9c0f 172b fba4 833e
fa22 7358 0cff 0bdf 9fff cc06 0fb3 4f3a
88dc 7414 148b 0a49 b8c6 8e56 e32f d254
f010 5a31 c4a2 8256 cc7c 8d67 1d4c 89c4
a276 e54c b8fb 0775 650d 8c04 f5e9 f200
0000 0049 454e 44ae 4260 82'''

class Window(pyglet.window.Window):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        img = "".join(imgData.split())

        img = binascii.unhexlify(img)

        file_object = io.BytesIO(img)

        img = pyglet.image.load("noname.png", file=file_object)

        self.sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img, 0, 0)

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.sprite.draw()

def main():
    window = Window(width=640, height=480, caption='Pyglet')
    pyglet.app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```